# ng-option starts from 2nd position

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a $scope.forumList with [1, 2, 3], I want to use ng-option start from 2, what should I do?

```
<select name="forum"
        ng-change="filterBlob()"
        ng-model='f'
        ng-options='f as f.name for f in forumList'
        required>
      </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you can do with `ng-options` but with `option`, one can do it as shown, using `ng-if`, in this [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/pznpwjog/).

Please find the code below:

HTML:

```
 <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
   <select ng-model="selected">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option ng-repeat="item in data" ng-value="item" ng-if="$index > 0">{{item}}
      </option>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
  var app = angular. module('app',[]);

  app.controller ('test', function ($scope){
       $scope.data = [1,2,3,4];
  });
```

Comment: Thx, I think this should be the only solution :(

Comment: What is WC? What is WC?

Answer (score 2):

Simply slice the array from js:

```
// In your javascript
var newForumList = scope.forumList.slice(1, scope.forumList.length);
```

And then use newForumList here

```
<select name="forum"
    ng-change="filterBlob()"
    ng-model='f'
    ng-options='f as f.name for f in newForumList'
    required>
</select>
```

Comment: It might be that `forumList` is in the scope object. So simply use `var newForumList = scope.forumList.slice(1, scope.forumList.length);` instead if that's the case.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `splice()` instead of `slice`

ex: 

`var a = [1,2,3,4]
var b = a.splice(1, a.length)`

returns `[2,3,4]`

Comment: Using `splice()` will mutate the original array which is likely not something the OP wants.